# error when configure sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I want to install SharePoint 2019 on windows server 2019 with SQLserver 2017 
I install pre-install for SharePoint and Sharepoint and SQLserver successfully but when I want to configure SharePoint I get below error, can anyone help me? 
[image]

Comment: Did you chose to download and install all the prerequisite software manually??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can occur if you chose to download and install all the prerequisite software manually, namely in this case the "WCF Data Services 5.6 Tools". If you are experiencing the error, "One or more types failed to load" , while creating a new SharePoint Farm, it's most likely caused by the installer executable being in a "blocked" state while it was installed.

When executables are downloaded from the internet, they are put into a "blocked" state by to OS, to prevent users from running malicious code. However, in this case, if the installer was in a blocked state when the "WCF Data Services 5.6 Tools" were installed, the install will "succeed' but will not be installed properly.

To resolve this issue:

1. Go to the properties of each prerequisite installer package that was downloaded manually and remove the block flag by selected "Unblock" and applying the changes.
2. After the file has been unblocked, re-run the installer and choose the repair option.
3. Finally, re-run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard to successfully create a new Farm.

For more information, check this [SharePoint fails to create Configuration Database for a new farm](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mikelee/2018/01/12/sharepoint-fails-to-create-configuration-database-for-a-new-farm/)

Comment: thanks it help me alot

Comment: @misa If this helped you, kindly upvote and mark it as answer, so that it will help others in future.